# Entitlement mediator cannot infer the transport information

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I have a proxy receiving a **GET request** and processing it, extracting a couple of parameters. 
**The proxy is:** "/services/proxyName/username/john/action/read"

I extract **"john"** and **"read"** in two different properties.

Then, I want to use the **"Entitlement Mediator"**, and evaluate a policy in a IS. I set up the right URL and user and password in the mediator, but I receive the next error:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: ClientUtils The system cannot infer the
>   transport information from the /services/proxyName/john/action/read
>   URL.

I don't understand why I receive this error. I just set up the correct URL (sure) and "admin" user-pass. Am I not using this mediator correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the identity server url  and user name password in entitlement mediator config
I guess some issue with your url.  Please check it again. Also please post the error message in Identity server, if you can see

url  : https://{Identity Server IP}:{Prot}/services/